# How to count the number of empty spaces in front of a String in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a YAML file which I am reading using VBA Excel plugin. I am getting a String of each line. I need to count the number of empty spaces in the front of the first line so that it will be a marker to find the next key. Let me know how to do that.

Comment: len(str)-len(trim(str)) or do you have to worry about spaces padding the right side as well?

Comment: @Jeeped Might as well allow for it and use `LTrim`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Function empty_spaces(str_input)
    empty_spaces = Len(str_input) - Len(LTrim(str_input))
End Function
```

harun24hr, your answer does not work with " My String " and similar.

Comment: Just you used function, I used sub. Else nothing difference. LTrim() will remove space both from front and end of string. Trim will remove only from front spaces.

Comment: It is exactly the opposite of what you are saying about ltrim and trim.

Comment: Yes. I explained opposite.

Comment: Then you probably realize why my code works and is different than yours? In yours, if you test with " My String " you will not get the expected answer...